Inconsistent environment variable behavior in docker
Consider the following dockerfile.
FROM phusion/baseimage:jammy-1.0.4

#Create user and add to sudo, then add home to path
RUN useradd u1
RUN adduser u1 sudo
RUN mkdir /home/u1
RUN chown -R u1:u1 /home/u1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/u1

#Create a little script and add it to path
RUN echo "echo Hello!" > /home/u1/t1.sh
RUN chown u1:u1 /home/u1/t1.sh
RUN chmod 700 /home/u1/t1.sh

#Check if script in path then run script - works fine
RUN echo $PATH
RUN t1.sh

#Same. This time script shows in path but does NOT work
RUN sudo -H -u u1 echo $PATH
RUN sudo -H -u u1 t1.sh

If you try to docker build this. The script will work just fine the first time. However, the second time - when I print the $PATH to screen as user u1 I see the folder containing the script in the path (this $PATH is same as when I echo it as root) - but the script behaves as if it is not in PATH. This seems inconsistent. Output something like this:
#14 [11/14] RUN echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/u1
#14 0.393 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/u1
#14 DONE 0.4s

#15 [12/14] RUN t1.sh
#15 0.478 Hello!
#15 DONE 0.5s

#16 [13/14] RUN sudo -H -u u1 echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/u1
#16 0.330 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/u1
#16 DONE 0.3s

#17 [14/14] RUN sudo -H -u u1 t1.sh
#17 0.364 sudo: t1.sh: command not found
#17 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c sudo -H -u u1 t1.sh" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [14/14] RUN sudo -H -u u1 t1.sh:
0.364 sudo: t1.sh: command not found


Is u1 a sudoer?  Have you tried su instead of sudo?

You should remove sudo from this setup.  You never need it in Docker.  The Dockerfile you show doesn't switch users at all, but if it did, you could switch back using the USER directive.
USER u1
RUN t1.sh

USER root
RUN t1.sh

Also consider putting the script in a directory that's normally on $PATH, if that's an option.
COPY t1.sh /usr/local/bin

(Most Dockerfiles I've seen that install sudo, including yours, do so in a not especially secure way.  Since you've added the user to the sudo group, so long as they ask politely, the user can do absolutely anything they want with no restrictions, up to the container boundary and Linux capability constraints.)

For security reasons, sudo resets the environment to a known state before it runs a command as another user.  That includes resetting $PATH.  So, sudo -u u1 t1.sh doesn't work because the script isn't in the default $PATH.
The previous line is a little trickier to explain.  Docker wraps RUN commands in a shell invocation, so the second-to-last line is equivalent to
RUN ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo -H -u u1 echo $PATH"]

So first the shell expands $PATH, and then it passes it (without any environment variable references) as an argument to sudo.  Staying in Dockeresque JSON-array syntax, the command that gets run after shell expansion and splitting is something like
RUN ["sudo", "-H", "-u", "u1", "echo", "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/u1"]

So even though sudo resets the environment, the environment variable expansion happens before this happens.
Also compare
sudo echo "$PATH"
sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'

where the latter command keeps $PATH as a string before invoking sudo, and then a shell (running as a different user) reëxpands it.

As the last example hints, none of this is specific to Docker, and you can demonstrate all of this same behavior on your host system.
The sudo -E option preserves the outer process's environment, and that would probably help this particular case, but you shouldn't need sudo at all here.

Thanks for this. This explains a number of things well. The reason I want to have a non-root user is that a number of applications, one being jupyter, issue warnings when you run them as root.

Actually just realizing my main reason for wanting to have a non-root user. It's that I have a local folder mounted to the docker container. When I ssh into docker as root and use it as my dev environment, all the mounted files in my host system end up being owned by root. That's annoying. If my user on the other hand has the right uid, it just maps nicely. What's the recommended way to handle this?

You can run the container with the matching user ID from the host; docker run -u $(id -u) for example.  You don't particularly need to "create the user" in the container, and the user doesn't need root permissions in most cases.

Thanks, running it this way appears to break all sorts of things. For example, I was not able to run ls (or really anything else) after getting into the container with docker exec -it <cont> bash
